# HTML to ASP.net web form page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

i have this page ASP.Net Web Forms Page

```
<!-- Sidebar menu -->               
    <div id="sidebar-menu ">

    <div id="topPanel"
    <asp:Table runat="server" ID="table_PageHeader">
        <asp:TableHeaderRow>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink_TruckList" runat="server" Text="Truck List" NavigateUrl="~/View/Trucklist.aspx" Font-Underline="false"></asp:HyperLink>
            </asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink_Reports" runat="server" Text="Reports" NavigateUrl="~/View/Reports.aspx" Font-Underline="false"></asp:HyperLink>
            </asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink_Profile" runat="server" Text="Profile" NavigateUrl="~/View/Profile.aspx" Font-Underline="false"></asp:HyperLink>
            </asp:TableHeaderCell>
        </asp:TableHeaderRow>
    </asp:Table>
</div>
```

want to implement this

```
<!-- Sidebar menu -->               
                <div id="sidebar-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html" style="font-size: 18px; color: black"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:black"></i> Truck Data </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#fakelink" style="font-size: 18px; color: black"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close" style="color:black"></i> Maintenance Record </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#fakelink" style="font-size: 18px; color: black"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="color:black"></i> Maintenance Schedule </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- End div #sidebar-menu -->
        </div><!-- End div .body .rows .scroll-y -->
    </div>
    <!-- END SIDEBAR -->
```

How can i insert the `<li>` and `<i>` in the Asp.net Web Form? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

At you interacting with the elements server side? If not just add the HTML as is. ASPX pages work fine with HTML elements.

If you want to interact with the elements server side, give them an ID and add `runat="server"`. E.g:

```
<div id="sidebar-menu" runat="server">
```

You can then access server side with `sidebar-menu`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to populate the unordered list from code behind. One option would be to make use of [HtmlGenericControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx) class.

Your list item mark up looks like this

```
<li><a href="index.html" style="font-size: 18px; color: black"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:black"></i> Truck Data </a></li>
```

I believe the text should be within the `<i></i>` tags. So it should look like this.

```
<li><a href="index.html" style="font-size: 18px; color: black"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:black">Truck Data</i></a></li>
```

Based on this you can just have a placeholder in the aspx page and set it from code behind. Here in the example I am just populating a list item. Based on your needs you can loop/ create additional list items.

*place holder in aspx*

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="sidemenu" runat="server" />
```

*code behind*

```
HtmlGenericControl list = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");

HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");

HyperLink a = new HyperLink();
a.NavigateUrl = "index.html";
a.Attributes.Add("style", "font-size: 18px; color: black");

HtmlGenericControl i = new HtmlGenericControl("i");
i.Attributes.Add("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign");
i.Attributes.Add("style", "color:black");
i.InnerText = "Truck Data";

a.Controls.Add(i);

li.Controls.Add(a);
list.Controls.Add(li);

sidemenu.Controls.Add(list);
```

*namespace*

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
```

*Generated markup*

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="index.html" style="font-size: 18px; color: black">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:black">Truck Data</i>
    </a>
<li>
</ul>
```

Comment: where should i input these?

Comment: @JohnPaulCirilos put the place holder in the aspx page. C# code in aspx.cs

Comment: @JohnPaulCirilos the code behind is the C# code that will go in the aspx.cs file. for example under Page_Load event. Also make sure to add the namespace in the aspx.cs file